# Here geocode API unpredictable endpoint results

Tags: here-api

It seems that HERE /geocode API endpoint response is sometimes unpredictable for not existing addresses.

To reproduce the problem we can use example page on HERE: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder

if you type: "włókniarzy 91, łódź"(this street number officially doesn't exist) for searchtext field, you will receive two results without street number and with two different postal codes.

But if you type "włókniarzy 89, łódź" or "włókniarzy 95, łódź" which dont exist as well, the response will be correct "Włókniarzy 52" - closest existing address.

Is there a way to receive only results with closest address and be sure to not receive address without street number in geocode endpoint?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please tell if you have used country filter Poland and other attribute. Or can you share the complete query you were trying.

Comment: The query is like that: `https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?lon=19.4734111&lat=51.73771300000001&language=pl&searchtext=włókniarzy 91, łódź&result_types=address,place&cs=pds&additionaldata=Country2,true` 
Of course I cut off api credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no switch that would do that, but if you know what the street name and HNR are in your address, then use the qualified search by specifying the address parts individually, e.g.

```
street=w%C5%82%C3%B3kniarzy
housenumber=91&
city=%C5%82%C3%B3d%C5%BA&
country=pol&
```

This will return 'aleja Włókniarzy, 91-073 Łódź, Polska'

In the initial query the Geocoder does not know what 91 is. As there is no house number (HNR) 91, the best match is the postal code. Once token "91" has been consumed it will not be used again to match a HNR, so the result is a street level match.